# Why do I get "Undefined method ::new" in simple classes?

Tags: ruby

I am writing an ATM-system-like socket/server solution. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm missing. For some reason, I get the following error running my stub test suite:

```
# Running tests:

.E

Finished tests in 0.002411s, 829.4384 tests/s, 414.7192 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_0001_connects_to_a_host_with_a_socket(AtmClient::connection):
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<SpoofServer:0x9dce2dc @clients=[], @server=#<TCPServer:fd 5>>
    /media/wildfyre/Files/Programming/KTH/progp/Atm/spec/client/SpoofServer.rb:12:in `start'
    /media/wildfyre/Files/Programming/KTH/progp/Atm/spec/client/client_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

My minispec file is:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper.rb'
require_relative '../../lib/AtmClient.rb'
require_relative 'SpoofServer.rb'

describe AtmClient do
  it "can be created with no arguments" do
    AtmClient.new.must_be_instance_of AtmClient
  end

  describe 'connection' do
    it "connects to a host with a socket" do
      spoof = SpoofServer.new.start
      client = AtmClient.new.connect
      spoof.any_incoming_connection?.must_be true
      spoof.kill
    end
  end
end
```

My SpoofServer file is:

```
require 'socket'

class SpoofServer

  def initialize
  end

  def start
    @clients = []
    @server = TCPServer.new 1234

    @listener_thread = new Thread do
      @clients.add @server.accept
    end
  end

  def any_incoming_connection?
    @clients.size > 0
  end

  def kill
    @listener_thread.exit
    @clients.each {|c| c.close}
  end

end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can read in the trace of the calls stack:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<SpoofServer:...>
    /.../spec/client/SpoofServer.rb:12:in `start'
```

The error is inside the `start` method defined in `SpoofServer.rb`, at line 12, the wrong line is:

```
@listener_thread = new Thread do
```

That should be:

```
@listener_thread = Thread.new do
```

As you have written it, what you are actually doing is to calling the `new` method passing the `Thread` class as argument. Since no `new` method is defined for instances of the `SpoofServer` class you get the `NoMethodError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

In body of instance method `SpoofServer#start`, you can't call the class method `SpoofServer.new` by `new`.